# Display Php Array result in an Html table

Tags: php

I was trying to display an array in php to an HTML table but there's an issue. I found several examples here in stack overflow, but they don't work for my case.

**Controller:**

```
<?php include('inc/db_connect.php');?>

<?php
try
{
  $sql = "SELECT id GroupName, VideoTITLE, ByArtist FROM videoclip";
  $result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  $error = 'unable to fetch data: '.$e->getMessage();
  include'error.html.php';
  exit();
}
$URLS = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch())
{
  $URLS[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'GroupName' => $row['GroupName'], 'VideoTITLE' => $row['VideoTITLE'], 'ByArtist'=> $row['ByArtist'] );
}
```

**html:**

```
<div id="table_admin" class="span7">
        <h3>Videoclip List</h3>

        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">

                <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Song name</th>
                <th>Group name </th>
                <th>Artist </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
            <?php foreach ($URLS as $URL){
                echo'<tbody>';
                echo'<tr>'; 
                echo'<td>'. $row['VideoTITLE']."</td>";
                echo'<td>'. $row['GroupName'].'</td>';
                echo'<td>'. $row['ByArtist'].'</td>';
                echo'<tr>';
                echo'</tbody>';
              }
            ?>

        </table>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're close:

```
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
    foreach ($URLS as $URL){
        echo'<tr>'; 
        echo'<td>'. $URL['VideoTITLE']."</td>";
        echo'<td>'. $URL['GroupName'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'. $URL['ByArtist'].'</td>';
        echo'<tr>';
    }
?>
</tbody>
```

Since you're taking the values of the `$URLS` array and calling each one `$URL` you need to refer to `$URL` for each row's value. Not the `$row` variable you originally used to populate the array from the database results.

FYI, you may want to look into [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to escape your data to help prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: thanks, this is a personal projects , i was planning to sanitize it after i finish building , just to make sure that i learn it right. Thanks , silly mistake , i never see that , just correct it

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data from the fetchRow is good to go, I see only one major bug in your html: change $row to $URL in your foreach loop. Also, you can mix PHP with HTML to make it a little more pretty:

```
<?php foreach ($URLS as $URL) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $URL['VideoTITLE']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $URL['GroupName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $URL['ByArtist']; ?></td>
    <tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

yea as john said, you have $URLs as $URL, but then your referring to an array calling $row in the for each.

the other thing is that you may want to take the tbody tags outside of the for each loop

Answer (score 1):

After getting the result from database please follow

```
<?php
  echo '<table>';
  echo '<thead>';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<th>Song name</th>';
  echo '<th>Group name </th>';
  echo '<th>Artist </th>';
  echo '</tr>';
  echo '</thead>'
  echo '<tbody>'; 
  foreach($URLS as $URL) {
    echo'<tr>'; 
    echo'<td>'. $URL['VideoTITLE']."</td>";
    echo'<td>'. $URL['GroupName'].'</td>';
    echo'<td>'. $URL['ByArtist'].'</td>';
    echo'<tr>';  
  }
  echo '</tbody>'; 
  echo '</table>'; 
?>
```

I hope this help you