# How to transform results of an sql query to an html table with specific format

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, pivot

I am trying to create some statistics for a library reservation system. The result of my sql query looks like the following structure.

```
total_no_students| department  | property       | month  
 241             | Physics     | undergraduate  | Nov
 236             | Physics     | undergraduate  | Dec
 254             | Physics     | postgraduate   | Nov
 210             | Physics     | postgraduate   | Dec
 193             | Architecture| undergraduate  | Nov
 181             | Architecture| undergraduate  | Dec
 127             | Architecture| postgraduate   | Nov
 292             | Architecture| postgraduate   | Dec
 134             | Biology     | undergraduate  | Nov
 188             | Biology     | undergraduate  | Dec
 129             | Biology     | postgraduate   | Nov
 219             | Biology     | postgraduate   | Dec
```

I am trying using php to write some code in order to create a statistics table with the following appearance:

```
    |Physics-undergrad|Physics-postgrad|Architecture-undergrad|Architecture-postgrad|
Nov |      241        |     254        |         193          |        127          |
Dec |      236        |     210        |         181          |        292          |
```

Any help how to trasform the query using php to the above table? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I assume you are able to get an array out of php. Then you can reduce the problem to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961388/display-php-array-result-in-an-html-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.month, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.department = 'Physics' AND A.property = 'undergraduate' THEN A.total_no_students ELSE 0 END) AS Physics_undergraduate, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.department = 'Physics' AND A.property = 'postgraduate' THEN A.total_no_students ELSE 0 END) AS Physics_postgraduate, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.department = 'Architecture' AND A.property = 'undergraduate' THEN A.total_no_students ELSE 0 END) AS Architecture_undergraduate, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.department = 'Architecture' AND A.property = 'postgraduate' THEN A.total_no_students ELSE 0 END) AS Architecture_postgraduate, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.department = 'Biology' AND A.property = 'undergraduate' THEN A.total_no_students ELSE 0 END) AS Biology_undergraduate, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.department = 'Biology' AND A.property = 'postgraduate' THEN A.total_no_students ELSE 0 END) AS Biology_postgraduate
FROM (...Your Existing Query...) AS A 
GROUP BY A.month
```

Comment: Thanks Sararsh! the problem is that the first structure is not the table but is already the result of my sql query.

Comment: I want something like a loop in order to create with php the above html table!

Comment: the first structure is the result of multiple joins of several tables!! It is not just the structure of a table!! So I think I cannot use your solution! Am I wrong?