# Laravel with Image Intervention: implode() not working

Tags: php, arrays, string, laravel

im currently trying to edit exif and iptc data with Image Intervention and Laravel. Up to this point it's working ok I guess, but when I try to use the [exif-method](http://image.intervention.io/api/exif), It returns an array instead of a string. OK I thought and tried to parse it into a string. I tried `serialize()`, but It returned a super ugly version of the array.

I stumbled upon the `implode()` function, which is what I need I think, but it somehow always returns the `Array to String conversion` Error even though I (think I) used it correctly..

Here's the code I used to parse it so far:

```
$exif = Image::make($path)->exif();
$exif = serialize($exif); //Super ugly version of the given array
```

And this:

```
$exif = Image::make($path)->exif();
$exif = implode(', ', $exif); //Returns "Array to string conversion" Error
```

Anyone got any Idea of how to fix this?

[GitHub Repo if needed](https://github.com/annazeller/mediadb)

Thank you :)

Comment: I think you mistook the function argument with the return value. In the documentation, it does say that is returns `Associative array of all Exif data available or mixed data for particular value. If no meta data can be found, method will return NULL.`. Print the array using a <pre> tag and print_r()(it will be a little but prettier) and see how to get the information you need.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response. I've tried what you told me. It returns the array correctly to my view but I wanted it to be in a table or something :D I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13961410/9094752), but it returned an Array to string conversion error.